# How to Send Print to Epson EM T82 POS Printer from Xamarin Forms App?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here I am starting a new activity for print data to my Epson TM T82 POS Thermal printer.And my Printer is connected through USB OTG Cable

```
public void printData()
        {
            String dataToPrint = "$big$This is a printer test$intro$posprinterdriver.com$intro$$intro$$cut$$intro$";

            Intent intentPrint = new Intent();

            intentPrint.SetAction(Intent.ActionSend);
            intentPrint.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, dataToPrint);
            intentPrint.SetType("text/plain");

            this.StartActivity(intentPrint);
        }
```

but this code is not working as expected.

so how to send few lines of text for print to Epson POS Thermal from Xamarin Forms App?

Comment: Are you using a USB-2-GO cable to connect it to your Android device?

Comment: Yes.I am using  USB-2-GO cabe to connect to my epson printer.I have another application that download from playstore and that application can print using this  USB-2-GO  cable.so how to setup my xamarin app to print?

Comment: What about that code is not working?

Comment: no its not working :( do you have any source code for this?

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: this code is running but nothing happen,while my printer is connected on my phone